# Both static and dynamic routing in a router?

Tags: routing

I've been reading about static and dynamic routing and can't help but wondering if it's possible to have both static and dynamic routing in a router?

Would it cause a conflict if we have both types of routing in a single router?

Is this a common/best practice?

Comment: Yes you can have both static and dynamic routing on a router. In fact, we use static combined with BGP protocol on our main routers. It can of course cause conflict, so you will have to look out for duplicates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Routers learn about routes to other networks either from other routers via routing protocols, or the routes are configured by the administrator, *i.e.* static routes.

There are many reasons why you might have both on your router. As you may already know, routers choose a particular route based on the best (longest) match to the destination. This is irrespective of whether the route is dynamic or static.

If both static and dynamic routes are the best match, routers use an attribute called Administrative Distance to choose the route. In almost all cases, static routes are preferred over dynamic ones.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely there is no issue in configuring static route and default route in same L3 devices

Generally router will pick route with low Administrative value( AD) when multiple routing protocols are configured for same destination ..

Default Administrative values (AD)

`1 ) Directly connected network = 0`

`2 ) static routing = 1`

`3) RIP = 120`

`4 ) EIGRP ==90`

`5) OSPF = 110`

`6) BGP external =20`

**Note : We have feasibility to changes AD value according to our requirement to priorities routes**